# How to initialize a Queue in the same statement

Tags: java, queue, abstract-data-type

In arrays, elements can be added at the beginning in the following manner

```
int[] array = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

similarly how to add multiple entries to a Queue? like,

```
Queue<Integer> queue = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you must choose which `Queue` implementation you wish to instantiate. Let's assume you are choosing `LinkedList` (which implements `Queue`).

Like any Collection, `LinkedList` has a constructor that takes a `Collection` and adds the elements of that `Collection` to the list.

For example:

```
Queue<Integer> queue = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{1,2,3,4,5}));
```

or (as PaulrBear correctly commented):

```
Queue<Integer> queue = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5));
```

Or you can take advantage of Java 8 Streams :

```
Queue<Integer> queue = IntStream.of(1,2,3,4,5)
                                .boxed()
                                .collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedList::new));
```

Comment: The first solution can be simplified to:
Queue<Integer> queue = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5));

Comment: @PaulrBear You are correct. Thanks for the comment.